# Storing multiple values for an enum

Tags: c#, enums

```
public enum ENUM_AccDebitCredit
{
    accDR = 1,
    accCR = 2
}
```

I declared this in a class as `public ENUM_AccDebitCreditDebitCredit { get; set; }`

In my code I tried by filling this `enum` from the datatable as follows

`DebitCredit = (ENUM_TransactionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ENUM_TransactionType), rsACC_AccountingRules.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DR"].ToString()) & (ENUM_TransactionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ENUM_TransactionType), rsACC_AccountingRules.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CR"].ToString());`

I would like to have multiple values to be stored in `DebitCredit`, how can I do this

My datatable is as follows

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("DR", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("CR", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(25, "1","2"); // enum values
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum Flags Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)

Comment: Mark your enum with `[Flags]` attribute if you want it to behave like flags. However you need values like 1, 2, 4 (unless Return is really both Sales and Purchase, which doesn't seem likely) and use `|` to combine them

Comment: If you want DebitCredit to be an array, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031299/array-property-syntax-in-c-sharp

Comment: I need to fill from Datatable values

Answer (score 1):

You could have a collection of `ENUM_TransactionType` or use `[Flags]` to represent each item as a bit flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want an *enumeration* to "mix" more than a value, you need to change your code to:

```
[Flags]
public enum ENUM_TransactionType
{
   None = 0,
   ttSales = 1,
   ttPurchase = 2,
   ttReturnIn = 4
}
```

Also, you need to use the bit-wise OR `|` operator instead of AND `&`:

```
ENUM_TransactionType value = ENUM_TransactionType.ttSales | ENUM_TransactionType.ttPurchase;
```

Comment: I need to assign the values from datatable is it possible

Comment: @Dotnet Of course. If the data column is of the enum type with flags attribute and you did the whole `|` ORs, there's no problem.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer i would consider making the property a nullable value instead of `None`.

Comment: @DanielA.White then you would have the possibility of unnecessary null reference exceptions, when a check for `.None` or `0` would suffice.

Comment: @DanielA.White Null or "none" has different meanings. Null is "not assigned" and "none" is "no value". In bit-wise operations you're adding complexity with your proposal, because I couldn't do "SomeEnum.HasFlag(...)" if it comes null. _None_ is more semantic in this case. I would use a nullable in other cases.

Comment: @DanielA.White In instance, _which is the default enum value for an enum without None?_ That's the best reason to use `None = 0`. Since .NET sets the first enum value as the default one, it makes the whole enum more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your most recent edit, the following is how you would do it:

```
public enum ENUM_AccDebitCredit
{
    accDR = 1,
    accCR = 2
}

var type1 = (ENUM_AccDebitCredit)int.Parse(rsACC_AccountingRules.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DR"].ToString());

var type2 = (ENUM_AccDebitCredit)int.Parse(rsACC_AccountingRules.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CR"].ToString());

myClass.DebitCard = type1 | type2;
```

You can either use the `[Flags]` attribute, or you can try something like this:

```
public enum ENUM_TransactionType
{
    ttSales = 1,
    ttPurchase = 2,
    ttReturnIn = 4,
}

myClass.DebitCard = ENUM_TransactionType.ttSales | ENUM_TransactionType.ttReturnIn;

bool hasSales = myClass.DebitCard & ENUM_TransactionType.ttSales > 0;
```

From a `DataTable` you could try this:

```
var type1 = (ENUM_TransactionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ENUM_TransactionType), rsACC_AccountingRules.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Drug"].ToString());

var type2 = (ENUM_TransactionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ENUM_TransactionType), rsACC_AccountingRules.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Drug1"].ToString());

myClass.DebitCard = type1 | type2;
```

This is a process called **bit masking**. For more information on the maths behind this process, see here: [Bit Masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

Comment: How can I assign the `myclass.DebitCard ` from a `datatable`

Comment: Hi thanks but instead of `ttSales and ttPurchase` the value that is storing in `myclass.DebitCard` is `ttReturnIn`

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but instead of the values having it is showing `3`

Comment: @Dotnet This is correct. To test for a value, you would do this: `if(myClass.DebitCard & ENUM_AccDebitCredit.accDR > 0) { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 0):

```
var DebitCredit = new List<ENUM_TransactionType>();
DebitCredit.Add((ENUM_TransactionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ENUM_TransactionType), rsACC_AccountingRules.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Drug"].ToString()));
DebitCredit.Add((ENUM_TransactionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ENUM_TransactionType), rsACC_AccountingRules.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Drug1"].ToString()));
```

Then you can test with:

```
if (DebitCredit.Contains(ENUM_TransactionType.ttSales)) etc.
```